# Filtering on association with criteria object in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Say that I have an entity `Profile` which has an association with an `Account` entity. I want to fetch the profile with `profileCode = 12345` *and* where its related `Account` has the e-mail address of `my@email.com`. So, I need to specify a condition on both entities.

For this I have created a custom repository `Repository\Profile` and now I am wondering how to implement this. I know that I can solve all of this with a "raw" DQL query or by using the query builder. However, I feel as if it is not as pretty as I would like, because it is very close to raw SQL. Sure the syntax is a bit different, but conceptually, I'd be thinking more in terms of SQL than OOP. I will be doing these kind of things a lot, so I am really trying to do it the best way.

I have done a bit of reading on the `Criteria` object (the documentation is sparse), and it really seems great as long as I am filtering on a single entity. I was unable to find any solution to using `Criteria` when filtering on associated entities.

So basically my question is: is there any way in which I can use the `Criteria` object for filtering on multiple entities directly from the database, and within a custom repository? I would *really* prefer to code this within a custom repository than the entity itself as I have seen some people do. Is this possible, or are there any good alternatives, or is plain DQL or the query builder really the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Criteria can only filter the associations on the entity itself, but if I understand your use case, you need to filter 2 levels deep, so it won't work.

You are trying to shape Doctrine into something that is not, by wanting to do things "your way". It will only hurt you in the long run. The solution is already there, it is perfectly fine to use DQL, especially in repositories.

Comment: I am not going two levels deep. I want to filter by an attribute on a direct association. For instance, `A` is associated with `B`. I want to find the entries of `A` where `B.something = 'some_value'`. I just want to be sure to have the work done in the database with one query if possible. Also, I am not trying to shape Doctrine into something that it's not; I simply wish to know if there is a way to do this "my way" that is built into Doctrine that I am not aware of. Otherwise I will use DQL just fine, but I'd prefer to use the `Criteria` object if possible. :-)

Comment: You cannot search on the property of a related entity with Criterias. You can only search on the properties of the entity itself.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought - unfortunately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why not, though not sure how your association is related. `One-to-One`,  `One-to-Many`, or `Many-to-Many`

If you're trying to retrieve records from the 3rd association depth level such as `Account.profile` -> `Profile.code` -> `Code.xxx (not id)` you would need to use DQL or or the QueryBuilder to establish what Profile and Code were joining Account with or resolve the Code entity to provide it to Criteria.

Assuming a `One-to-Many` where one Account has many Profiles. You can also optionally just define it within the entity itself to make it easier to manage and reduce having the extra call to `getProfiles()`.

**Repository Usage**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class AccountRepository extends EntityRepository {
   
    /**
     * @var string|Account $accountOrEmail
     * @var string $code
     * @return Profile|null
     */
    public function getAccountProfileByEmailAndCode($accountOrEmail, $code)
    {
         try{
             $account = ($accountOrEmail instanceof Account ? $accountOrEmail: $this->findOneBy(['email' => $accountOrEmail]));
             if (!$account instanceof Account) {
                 throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unknown Account Specified.');
             }
             $criteria = Criteria::create()->setMaxResult(1);
             $expr = $criteria::expr();
             $criteria->where($expr->eq('code', $code));

             return $account->getProfiles()->matching($criteria)->first() ?: null;
         } catch(\Exception $e) {
             return null;
         }
    }

}
```

```
$accountRepo = $em->getRepository('\Entities\Account');
$profile = $accountRepo->getAccountProfileByEmailAndCode('my@email.com', '12345');
```

---

**Entity usage**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AccountRepository")
 */
class Account {

    // ...
    
    public function getProfiles(Criteria $criteria = null)
    {
        if ($criteria instanceof Criteria) {
            return $this->profiles->matching($criteria);
        }

        return $this->profiles;
    }

    /**
     * @var string $code
     * @return null|Profile
     */
    public function getProfileByCode($code)
    {
         $criteria = Criteria::create()->setMaxResult(1);
         $expr = $criteria::expr();
         $criteria->where($expr->eq('code', $code));

         return $this->getProfiles($criteria)->first() ?: null;
    }

}
```

```
$account = $em->getRepository('\Entities\Account')->findOneBy(['email' => 'my@email.com']);
$profile = $account->getProfileByCode('12345');
```